# Como localizar e abrir arquivo .txt, acrescentar informações e salvar? Dentro do Android

Tags: delphi, delphi-berlin

Estou utilizando Delphi Berlin 10.1.
Não consegui utilizar o OpenDialog, ele simplesmente não abre dentro do Android.

Procurei na raiz do android que fica em /storage/emulated/0/
onde eu deveria encontrar um arquivo **.txt**
O mesmo procedimento para Desktop Win32 esta ok.

---

Consegui pegar o arquivo.

```
procedure TF_form1.FileSearch(PathName, FileName: string; const InDir: boolean);
var
  Rec: TSearchRec;
  path: string;
  LItem: TListViewItem;
begin
  path := IncludeTrailingBackslash(PathName);
  if FindFirst(path + FileName, faAnyFile - faDirectory, Rec) = 0 then
      repeat
        LItem := ListView.Items.Add;
        LItem.Text := path + Rec.Name;
      until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;


  If not InDir then
  begin
    TabControl.TabIndex := 0;
    exit;
  end;

  if FindFirst(path + '*.*', faDirectory, Rec) = 0 then
      repeat
        if ((Rec.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0) and (Rec.Name <> '.') and (Rec.Name <> '..') then
          FileSearch(path + Rec.Name, FileName, true);
      until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
end;
```

Mas, ainda  não consegui utilizar o OpenDialog. Se tiver algo similar, avise-me.

Comment: OpenDialog serve apenas para win32/64 e OS-X.
Você pode usar o "JFileDialog" no android. Ou acessar este link que possui um exemplo de implementação:
http://bluexmas.tistory.com/427